# Calling function pointer from another class

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with calling an unassigned function pointer in an object stored in an unordered_multimap.

**Listener.h**

```
class Listener
{
public:
    Listener(){}
    void( *fun1 )(Variant) = NULL;
};
```

**Messenger.h**

```
class Messenger
{
public:
    void post( std::string type, void( *function )(Variant v1), Variant v1 ) {
        auto its = m_listeners.equal_range( type );
        for( auto it = its.first; it != its.second; it++ )
            it->second.fun1( v1 );
    }

protected:
    std::unordered_multimap<std::string, Listener> m_listeners;
};
```

However when trying to compile I get an error `C2228: left of '.fun1' must have class/struct/union`.

The idea is that these classes are inherited and `fun1` can be assigned to a function for different objects which can then be called via `post` from other objects that are subscribed to a certain post type

Comment: You need an additional dereference, i.e. `it->second->fun1( v1 );`. `equal_range` returns pairs of *iterators*.

Comment: `it->second->fun1( v1 );` results in `Error: expression must have pointer type`

Comment: sorry had a senior moment, remove `second`: `it->fun1( v1 );`

Comment: That doesn't work either, `it` is a `std::pair<const std::string, Listener>` type

Comment: Never mind, I'm a moron, sorry!

Comment: It's `it->second->*fun1( v1 );` actually.

Comment: I get `Error: identifier "fun1" is undefined` with that, is my declaration for the function pointerin `Listener.h` wrong?

Comment: @user1560249 Ah I see, it's actually not a member function pointer in the definition. You'll need: `*(it->second->fun1)( v1 );` but it's unrelated to a `Listener` object then.

Comment: `Error: expression must have a pointer type` for `it`, I've tried fiddling around with the answer in the linked duplicate, modifying `Listener` to use `void( Listener::*fun1 )( Variant )` to no avail

Comment: CNR: [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/3GN4P1). Post your toolchain, and command-line for compilation in your question (and make sure if using clang or gcc you're using `-std=c++11`)

Comment: Works for me too - http://ideone.com/44RdJA

Comment: Okay, well now it seems to be working, not sure what happened there since it seemed like it should be pretty straightforward, thanks for the help guys